# Filling Tables with data from XLSX files Python3 sqlite3 openpyxl

Tags: python, sqlite

I am looking for a more efficient way to fill my tables other than to use [for xx in range xx] and adding a new row to the table. The spread sheets have thousands of rows so this takes a long time.

```
import openpyxl
import sqlite3
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry.xlsx')
print(wb.get_sheet_names())
#GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry')
print(sheet.max_row)
#577463 rows

wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('GlobalLandTemperaturesByState.xlsx')
print(wb2.get_sheet_names())
#GlobalLandTemperaturesByState
sheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('GlobalLandTemperaturesByState')
print(sheet2.max_row)
#645676 rows
wb3=openpyxl.load_workbook('GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCity.xlsx')
print(wb3.get_sheet_names())
#GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCi
sheet3 = wb3.get_sheet_by_name('GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCi')
print(sheet3.max_row)
#239178 rows

    connection = sqlite3.connect('temperature.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE Countries
        (Date DATE, AverageTemperature REAL, AverageTemperatureUncertainty REAL, Country TEXT)

    ''')
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE States
        (Date DATE, AverageTemperature REAL, AverageTemperatureUncertainty REAL, State TEXT, Country TEXT)

    ''')
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE Towns
        (Date DATE, AverageTemperature REAL, AverageTemperatureUncertainty REAL, City TEXT, Country TEXT, Latitude REAL, Longitude REAL)

    ''')
```

## all tables will be stores in the same db file

## 1 sheet per workbook

Thanks, ~python noobie~

Comment: Try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to convert xlsx file to csv file seems to be faster